# Why doesn't the LotView show draw lot results on ResultView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My SwiftUI app doesn't show updated data on the SubView after NavigationLink and jump to a new View.

It is a sign app, HomeView goes to PrayerView, pressing "drawlot" button, func `drawLot()` will draw lots from what lots it has in Core Data database and return several attributes of entity, representing the information of the lot.
HomeView will go into PrayerView, then PaymentView and then ResultView.
PrayerView will show LotView, which shows draw lot results, after pressing pressing "drawlot" button.
ResultView will show the same LotView after payment is done on PaymentView, and more details.
But LotView of ResultView does not show drawlot results, and it remains default screen, with 0 or empty data display.
Here is the code of ResultView:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ResultView: View {
    // 設置 ResultViewModel 的環境對象
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultViewModel
    @ObservedObject var lotViewModel: LotViewModel
    @ObservedObject var prayerViewModel: PrayerViewModel
    var container: NSPersistentContainer

    
    init(container: NSPersistentContainer) {
        self.container = container
        lotViewModel = LotViewModel(container: container)
        prayerViewModel = PrayerViewModel(container: container)
        viewModel = ResultViewModel(container:container)
    }
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                // 顯示籤詩相關屬性
                LotView(viewModel: lotViewModel)
                            
                    .padding()// 在此處添加 LotView
                                  
                // 顯示吉凶和分析內容
                Text("吉凶：\(viewModel.lotViewModel.luckLevel)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                Text("分析內容：\(lotViewModel.analysis)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                
                // 顯示對應問題種類的屬性內容
               VStack {
                    //Text("\(viewModel.selectedCategory):")
                        //.font(.headline)
                       // .fontWeight(.bold)
                       // .padding(.top, 20)
                    
                    if viewModel.selectedCategory == "願望" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.wish)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "疾病" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.illness)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "盼望的人" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.person)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "遺失物" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.lostItem)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "搬家" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.moving)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "蓋新居" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.newHome)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "嫁娶" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.marriage)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "交往" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.relationship)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "旅行" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.travel)
                    } else if viewModel.selectedCategory == "結親緣" {
                        Text(lotViewModel.family)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                Spacer()
                
                // 點擊返回主畫面的按鈕
                /*NavigationStack{
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            viewModel.showHomeView()
                        }) {
                            Text("返回")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                .padding(.bottom, 50)
                        }
                    }
                        .navigationDestination(isPresented:$viewModel.isPresentingHomeView){
                            HomeView(selectedGod: "玄天上帝", container: container)
                        }
            }*/
       }
    }
}
struct ResultView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppDataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }
        })
        return ResultView(container:container)     
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Anything need to be adjusted? I have tried my best to make it as clear as possible..

Comment: The code you posted won't run as you haven't included all of the necessary views and view models. Please read the links I attached above.

Comment: Sorry I am new here.. how to include several swift file codes here? I have got 8 files including 4 view files and 4 viewModel files, and they are all related..Could you tell the way how to present it here? Thank you very much

Comment: The way you already posted the code. Just add spaces between. It doesn't matter if it is all on one window. However, this is where the minimal part comes in. We don't want you to post all your code, just enough that builds, runs and shows your problem. It is easiest to make a new project, and make a simplified app in there, and then post that code, not your full set of files.